# Estimating a response value based on known parameters

Tags: sas

SAS newbie here.

My question is about `PROC REG` in SAS; let's assume I have already created a model and now I would like to use this model, and known predictor variables to estimate a response value.

Is there a clean and easy way of doing this in SAS? So far I've been manually grabbing the intercept and  the coefficients from the output of my model to calculate the response variable but as you can imagine it can get pretty nasty when you have a lot of covariates. Their user's guide is pretty cryptic...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Reese is correct.  Here is some sample code to get you up the learning curve faster:

```
/*Data to regress*/
data test;
do i=1 to 100;
    x1 = rannor(123);
    x2 = rannor(123)*2 + 1;
    y = 1*x1 + 2*x2 + 4*rannor(123);
    output;
end;
run;

/*Data to score*/
data to_score;
_model_ = "Y_on_X";
y = .;
x1 = 1.5;
x2 = -1;
run;


/*Method 1: just put missing values on the input data set and
  PROC REG will do it for you*/
data test_2;
set test to_score;
run;

proc reg data=test_2 alpha=.01 outest=est;
Y_on_X: model y = x1 x2;
output out=test2_out(where=(y=.)) p=predicted ucl=UCL_Pred lcl=LCL_Pred;
run;
quit;

proc print data=test2_out;
run;


/*Method 2: Use the coefficients and the to_score data with
  PROC SCORE*/
proc score data=to_score score=est out=scored type=parms;
var x1 x2;
run;

proc print data=scored;
var Y_on_X X1 X2;
run;
```

Answer (score 3):

2 ways:

1. Append the data you want into the data set you're going to use to get estimates but leave the y value blank. Grab the estimates using the output statement from proc reg.
2. Use Proc Score
   http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_score_sect018.htm